# Trigger error on submit if specific checkbox is selected from a checkbox group

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent form submission and trigger span error to appear on submit if checkbox id="check1" is selected.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <span id="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="1">
        <label>check1</label> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" value="2">
        <label>check2</label> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" id="check3" value="3">
        <label>check3</label> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check4" id="check4" value="4">
        <label>check4</label> <br>

        <span class="error">One or more of your selection is wrong.</span>
    </span>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Check out event.preventDefault() http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: and what is your problem? Could you reproduce it in a fiddle? Does your console report any error?

Comment: can you pls share some code here so that we will get some idea what exactly you are doing?

Comment: sorry, just added the html markup code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery,

JS:

```
$('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    if( $('input#check1').is(":checked") ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('span.error').removeClass("hide");
    }   
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="error hide">One or more of your selection is wrong.</span>
```

CSS:

```
   .hide{
       display: none;
   }
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tHCp/7/)

Comment: Thanks for that @Kyo I have other form elements in the same form that's going thorough validations as well, example radio buttons. Right now I am getting the error appearing if check1 is checked which is great however if I uncheck it but have a validation issue with the radio buttons the span error still appears, is there a way to toggle it, so if checked error appears if not check error hides.

Comment: Updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9tHCp/12/

Comment: That's great, thank you very much for your help, appreciate that! @Kyo

Answer (score 0):

First of all make your submit button to button type and call one javascript function on onclick event of button as below -

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="validateSubmission()">

// javascript function
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateSubmission()
    {
      var checkboxSelected = document.getElementById('check1').checked;
      if(checkboxSelected)
     {
       // show your span error alert 
     }
      else
    {
      // submit your form here like below
      var forms = document.getElementsByName('form1');
      forms[0].submit();
     }
    }
</script>
```